# Creating a custom counter in Spark based on dataframe conditions

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

#### Current Dataset

```
+---+-----+-----+-----+----+
| ID|Event|Index|start| end|
+---+-----+-----+-----+----+
|  1|  run|    0|start|null|
|  1|  run|    1| null|null|
|  1|  run|    2| null|null|
|  1| swim|    3| null| end|
|  1|  run|    4|start|null|
|  1| swim|    5| null|null|
|  1| swim|    6| null| end|
|  1|  run|    7|start|null|
|  1|  run|    8| null|null|
|  1|  run|    9| null|null|
|  1| swim|   10| null| end|
|  1|  run|   11|start|null|
|  1|  run|   12| null|null|
|  1|  run|   13| null| end|
|  2|  run|   14|start|null|
|  2|  run|   15| null|null|
|  2|  run|   16| null|null|
|  2| swim|   17| null| end|
|  2|  run|   18|start|null|
|  2| swim|   19| null|null|
|  2| swim|   20| null|null|
|  2| swim|   21| null|null|
|  2| swim|   22| null| end|
|  2|  run|   23|start|null|
|  2|  run|   24| null|null|
|  2|  run|   25| null| end|
|  3|  run|   26|start|null|
|  3|  run|   27| null|null|
|  3| swim|   28| null|null|
+---+-----+-----+-----+----+
```

#### Dataset I'm After

```
+---+-----+-----+-----+----+-------+
| ID|Event|Index|start| end|EventID|
+---+-----+-----+-----+----+-------+
|  1|  run|    0|start|null|      1|
|  1|  run|    1| null|null|      1|
|  1|  run|    2| null|null|      1|
|  1| swim|    3| null| end|      1|
|  1|  run|    4|start|null|      2|
|  1| swim|    5| null|null|      2|
|  1| swim|    6| null| end|      2|
|  1|  run|    7|start|null|      3|
|  1|  run|    8| null|null|      3|
|  1|  run|    9| null|null|      3|
|  1| swim|   10| null| end|      3|
|  1|  run|   11|start|null|      4|
|  1|  run|   12| null|null|      4|
|  1|  run|   13| null| end|      4|
|  2|  run|   14|start|null|      1|
|  2|  run|   15| null|null|      1|
|  2|  run|   16| null|null|      1|
|  2| swim|   17| null| end|      1|
|  2|  run|   18|start|null|      2|
|  2| swim|   19| null|null|      2|
|  2| swim|   20| null|null|      2|
|  2| swim|   21| null|null|      2|
|  2| swim|   22| null| end|      2|
|  2|  run|   23|start|null|      3|
|  2|  run|   24| null|null|      3|
|  2|  run|   25| null| end|      3|
|  3|  run|   26|start|null|      1|
|  3|  run|   27| null|null|      1|
|  3| swim|   28| null|null|      1|
+---+-----+-----+-----+----+-------+
```

I am trying to create the above **EventID** Column. Is there a way to create a counter inside of a udf that updates based on column conditions? Note, I'm not sure if a UDF is the best approach here.

Here is my current thinking-logic:

- When a "start" value is seen, start counting.
- When an "end" value is seen, end counting
- Every time a new **ID** is seen, reset the counter to 1

Thank you all for any assistance.

Here is the raw code to produce the current dataframe:

```
# Current Dataset

data = [
       (1, "run", 0, 'start', None),
       (1, "run", 1,  None,   None),
       (1, "run", 2,  None,   None),
       (1, "swim", 3, None,   'end'),
       (1, "run",  4, 'start',None),
       (1, "swim", 5, None,   None),
       (1, "swim", 6, None,   'end'),
       (1, "run",7, 'start',   None),
       (1, "run",8, None,   None),
       (1, "run",9, None,   None),
       (1, "swim",10, None,   'end'),
       (1, "run",11, 'start',   None),
       (1, "run",12, None,   None),
       (1, "run",13, None,   'end'),
       (2, "run",14, 'start',   None),
       (2, "run",15, None,   None),
       (2, "run",16, None,   None),
       (2, "swim",17, None,   'end'),
       (2, "run",18, 'start',   None),
       (2, "swim",19, None,   None),
       (2, "swim",20, None,   None),
       (2, "swim",21, None,   None),
       (2, "swim",22, None,   'end'),
       (2, "run",23, 'start',   None),
       (2, "run",24, None,   None),
       (2, "run",25, None,   'end'),
       (3, "run",26, 'start',   None),
       (3, "run",27, None,   None),
       (3, "swim",28, None,   None)
        ]

schema = StructType([
  StructField('ID', IntegerType(),True), \
  StructField('Event', StringType(),True), \
  StructField('Index', IntegerType(),True), \
  StructField('start', StringType(),True), \
  StructField('end', StringType(),True)
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)
df.show(30)
```

Comment: In your current setup, you don't need the extra condition to end counting on end since there will always be start in the following row. Is that a correct assumption? If not, can you provide a rule what to do in that case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a window function:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window.partitionBy('ID').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding,0).orderBy('index')
df.withColumn('EventId', F.sum(F.when(F.col('start') == 'start', 1).otherwise(0))\
    .over(w)).orderBy('ID', 'Index').show(100)
```

results in

```
+---+-----+-----+-----+----+-------+
| ID|Event|Index|start| end|EventId|
+---+-----+-----+-----+----+-------+
|  1|  run|    0|start|null|      1|
|  1|  run|    1| null|null|      1|
|  1|  run|    2| null|null|      1|
|  1| swim|    3| null| end|      1|
|  1|  run|    4|start|null|      2|
|  1| swim|    5| null|null|      2|
|  1| swim|    6| null| end|      2|
|  1|  run|    7|start|null|      3|
|  1|  run|    8| null|null|      3|
|  1|  run|    9| null|null|      3|
|  1| swim|   10| null| end|      3|
|  1|  run|   11|start|null|      4|
|  1|  run|   12| null|null|      4|
|  1|  run|   13| null| end|      4|
|  2|  run|   14|start|null|      1|
|  2|  run|   15| null|null|      1|
|  2|  run|   16| null|null|      1|
|  2| swim|   17| null| end|      1|
|  2|  run|   18|start|null|      2|
|  2| swim|   19| null|null|      2|
|  2| swim|   20| null|null|      2|
|  2| swim|   21| null|null|      2|
|  2| swim|   22| null| end|      2|
|  2|  run|   23|start|null|      3|
|  2|  run|   24| null|null|      3|
|  2|  run|   25| null| end|      3|
|  3|  run|   26|start|null|      1|
|  3|  run|   27| null|null|      1|
|  3| swim|   28| null|null|      1|
+---+-----+-----+-----+----+-------+
```

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate dense_rank based on the most recent start time:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'laststart', 
    F.last(F.when(F.col('start') == 'start', F.col('Index')), True).over(Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy('Index'))
).withColumn(
    'EventID', 
    F.dense_rank().over(Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy('laststart'))
)

df2.show(999)
+---+-----+-----+-----+----+---------+-------+
| ID|Event|Index|start| end|laststart|EventID|
+---+-----+-----+-----+----+---------+-------+
|  1|  run|    0|start|null|        0|      1|
|  1|  run|    1| null|null|        0|      1|
|  1|  run|    2| null|null|        0|      1|
|  1| swim|    3| null| end|        0|      1|
|  1|  run|    4|start|null|        4|      2|
|  1| swim|    5| null|null|        4|      2|
|  1| swim|    6| null| end|        4|      2|
|  1|  run|    7|start|null|        7|      3|
|  1|  run|    8| null|null|        7|      3|
|  1|  run|    9| null|null|        7|      3|
|  1| swim|   10| null| end|        7|      3|
|  1|  run|   11|start|null|       11|      4|
|  1|  run|   12| null|null|       11|      4|
|  1|  run|   13| null| end|       11|      4|
|  2|  run|   14|start|null|       14|      1|
|  2|  run|   15| null|null|       14|      1|
|  2|  run|   16| null|null|       14|      1|
|  2| swim|   17| null| end|       14|      1|
|  2|  run|   18|start|null|       18|      2|
|  2| swim|   19| null|null|       18|      2|
|  2| swim|   20| null|null|       18|      2|
|  2| swim|   21| null|null|       18|      2|
|  2| swim|   22| null| end|       18|      2|
|  2|  run|   23|start|null|       23|      3|
|  2|  run|   24| null|null|       23|      3|
|  2|  run|   25| null| end|       23|      3|
|  3|  run|   26|start|null|       26|      1|
|  3|  run|   27| null|null|       26|      1|
|  3| swim|   28| null|null|       26|      1|
+---+-----+-----+-----+----+---------+-------+
```